# Find rows where the value in column 1 exists in colunm2

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to find instances where a user has entered a person with their name backwards and then entered the person again correctly.

```
FirstName    LastName
----------------------
Doc          Jones
Jones        Doc
Doc          Holiday
John         Doe
```

I want to get

```
Doc Jones
Jones Doc
```

I tried

```
Select FirstName, LastName 
From People
Where FirstName Like '%' + LastName + '%'
```

but I get no results and I know there are multiple instances of this. I know I'm overlooking something easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for the sake of completeness. You can also use `INTERSECT`:

```
Select FirstName, LastName
From People

INTERSECT

Select LastName, FirstName
From People
```

This will return only one pair of matching rows, i.e.:

```
+-----------+----------+
| FirstName | LastName |
+-----------+----------+
| Doc       | Jones    |
| Jones     | Doc      |
+-----------+----------+
```

even if original data has `Doc Jones` or `Jones Doc` more than once:

```
DECLARE @People TABLE ([FirstName] varchar(50), [LastName] varchar(50));

INSERT INTO @People ([FirstName], [LastName]) VALUES
('Doc', 'Jones'),
('Doc', 'Jones'),
('Jones', 'Doc'),
('Doc', 'Holiday'),
('John', 'Doe');
```

Comment: Very cleaver, will have to check this.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT P1.FirstName,    P1.LastName
FROM People P1
JOIN People P2
  ON P1.FirstName  =  P2.LastName
 AND P2.FirstName  =  P1.LastName
```

The problem I see is you dont have some form of ID you wont have a way to see what are the rows duplicated between lot of duplicates.

So maybe this is better

```
SELECT P1.*,  P2.*
FROM People P1
JOIN People P2
  ON P1.FirstName =  P2.LastName
 AND P2.FirstName =  P1.LastName
 AND P1.FirstName <  P1.LastName
```

And you get

```
Doc Jones Jones Doc
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. We have an ID field but I just didn't include it here. I'm new to SQL and this. Thanks again for your help

Answer (score 1):

I would be inclined to approach this using `exists`:

```
select p.*
from people p
where exists (select 1
              from people p2
              where p2.firstname = p.lastname and
                    p2.lastname = p.firstname
             );
```

In your case, the difference between this and a `join` probably doesn't matter.  However, if there were the possibility of many rows with the same values, then there would be a significant difference in performance and in the result set.  This is guaranteed not to return duplicates -- well, except for one row for each swapped name.